# Extract multiple substrings before / after certain chars

Tags: c#, string, substring, chars

I'm looking to get multiple certain substrings before and after certain chars...e.g.:

**"Capacity : Less than 10 litres |Power : Up to 1400 W|Type of surface : Carpets and rugs"**

I need to get these in 2 lists of strings (or datatable or something like it for inserting into DB) getting all strings **before** and **after** the ':' char.. For example, 1st list from above would look like: 'Capacity, Power, Type of Surface' and their corresponding values: 'Less than 10 litres, Up to 1400 W, Carpets and rugs'

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.  (in C# if possible!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may wanna use a `Dictionary` instead of a list:

```
var str = "Capacity : Less than 10 litres |Power : Up to 1400 W|Type of surface : Carpets and rugs";

var values = str
            .Split('|')
            .ToDictionary(
                  x => x.Split(':')[0],
                  x => x.Split(':')[1]);
```